# How to dynamically allocate data struct array with nullptr and struct members?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, heap-memory, nullptr

I am newly to programming with c++ and I am trying to allocate memory for array of struct. The problem is I don't know the size of elements inside it at compile time. I want the "empty" part to be allocated with null pointers. I run this code below, but there is no the output I expected to be. Could somebody help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct ones{
    int a;
    int b;
}ones;

ones** twoes = nullptr;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        twoes[i]= nullptr;
    }
    
        cout<< "i dont get HERE" << endl;
  
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {  
        twoes[i]= new ones;
        twoes[i]->a = 2;
        cout<< twoes[i]->a <<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll say it before everyone else does -- save yourself a lot of trouble and declare a `std::vector<ones>` to manage the array for you.  Trying to do manual memory management is unnecessary pain.

Comment: `twoes` doesn't point to anything, so `twoes[i]` is undefined.  You need to allocate an array of `ones*` for it to point to.  Or just use `std::vector<ones>` and call it a day.

Comment: 1) An array of structs cannot hold `nullptr`. An array of **pointers to** structs could, though. 2) In your code, there is no "'empty' part" of your array. Why do you think there is one? How big do you think it is, and why?

Comment: `ones** twoes = nullptr;` followed by (the first iteration of the first loop) `twoes[0] = nullptr`  has undefined behaviour since it dereferences a null pointer (`twoes` is `nullptr` so `twoes[0]` does not exist).   Try changing the definition of `twoes` to `ones *twoes[5]` - which ensures `twoes[0]` through to `twoes[4]` are actually pointers.

Comment: Thank you Miles Budnek and Peter. I figured out it should be ones** twoes = new ones*[5].